# How can disable TAB to execute selected line in `counsel-M-x`?

Tags: key-bindings, counsel

I am using `counsel-M-x`, it has little bit different behavior than `smex`, where `TAB` may execute the line.

Is it possible to use `TAB` only for toggling where I just want to disable feature to execute the found command if its solo match?

---

Basic example:
Type `M-x list-packages` enter and pressing two TABs one after another will executute `list-packages`. I just don't want runnung the command to take place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(ivy-define-key ivy-minibuffer-map (kbd "TAB") #'ivy-partial)
```

Originally <kbd>TAB</kbd> binds to `ivy-partial-or-done`. Note that in ivy terms, "done" means your term "execute", whereas "partial" means to try to complete in minibuffer. So switching from `ivy-partial-or-done` to `ivy-partial` will keep the tab-complete function but prevent execution.

Comment: I am having following error message: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function ivy-define-key)`

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this answers the question: what does `ivy-partial` do?

Comment: @alper Which version of `ivy` are you using? Don't you have [these lines](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/1c6b3da377a840e898b14020133f59fca9ceea1c/ivy.el#L312-L322) in the `ivy.el` source code?

Comment: @NickD Edited. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I have `0.13.4` version . Seems like there is `ivy-partial ()`function which couldn't find from my init file

Comment: Please note that I cannot use `(ivy-mode)` because it does not make work along with  https://github.com/minad/consult

Comment: @alper Are you saying that you are not using `counsel` any more? I'm a bit confused here since `ivy` surely is a dependency of `counsel`.

Comment: I am still using `counsel-M-x` but I am using consult as well. When I add `(ivy-mode)` into my config file I observe that `consult` does not function well so I don' add that line which leads `ivy-partial` function not to find

Comment: @alper I don't understand how that works. Don't you have [this line](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/1c6b3da377a840e898b14020133f59fca9ceea1c/counsel.el#L43) in your `counsel.el` source code?

Comment: I just installed and using  `counsel-M-x` . I don't understand it as well if I have `(ivy-mode)` in my init file `consult` does not work ...